# Android HDR scene mode

Tags: android, camera, hdr

I'm trying to implement an app that take photos using HDR mode.
My phone is an Galaxy S3 and in the native camera, I have the option to enable HDR.
However, I'm getting an exception when setting it in the app.
I set the HDR like this:

```
params.setSceneMode("hdr");
```

Then, when I try to set the params back:

```
mCamera.setParameters(params);
```

I get this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: setParameters failed
    at android.hardware.Camera.native_setParameters(Native Method)
    at android.hardware.Camera.setParameters(Camera.java:1606)
    at com.myapp.Preview.surfaceCreated(Preview.java:131)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:610)
    at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:93)
    at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:182)
    at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:864)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2142)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1249)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6364)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:791)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:561)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:777)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Any help? What am I doing wrong?
I have also tried to use the constant:

```
params.setSceneMode(Parameters.SCENE_MODE_HDR);
```

Same error.

Thanks!

Comment: It's possible that the camera does not *actually* support it and the native app "fakes" HDR mode, as some 3rd party apps do. Does it show up as supported with `getSupportedSceneModes()`?

Comment: That's the problem. When I use getSupportedSceneModes() it doesn't return hdr. Do you know a library for me to use to make this "fake" HDR?